# Using vectorisation with numpy for the Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, bellman-ford

I've been having a go at writing the Bellman Ford algoritm for finding the shortest path in a graph and while I've got a working solution it doesn't run very quickly and I'm led to believe it could be faster if I use numpy instead of my current approach.

This is the solution I have using for loops:

```
import os                    
file = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/g_small.txt")

vertices, edges = map(lambda x: int(x), file.readline().replace("\n", "").split(" "))

adjacency_list = [[] for k in xrange(vertices)]
for line in file.readlines():
    tail, head, weight = line.split(" ")
    adjacency_list[int(head)-1].append({"from" : int(tail), "weight" : int(weight)})

n = vertices

shortest_paths = []
s=2

cache = [[0 for k in xrange(vertices)] for j in xrange(vertices)]
cache[0][s] = 0

for v in range(0, vertices):
    if v != s:
    cache[0][v] = float("inf")

# this can be done with numpy I think?
for i in range(1, vertices):
    for v in range(0, vertices):
        adjacent_nodes = adjacency_list[v]

        least_adjacent_cost = float("inf")
        for node in adjacent_nodes:
            adjacent_cost = cache[i-1][node["from"]-1] + node["weight"]
            if adjacent_cost < least_adjacent_cost:
                least_adjacent_cost = adjacent_cost

        cache[i][v] = min(cache[i-1][v], least_adjacent_cost)

shortest_paths.append([s, cache[vertices-1]])

for path in shortest_paths:
    print(str(path[1]))

shortest_path = min(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: x[1], shortest_paths)))  
print("Shortest Path: " + str(shortest_path))
```

The input file looks like this -> https://github.com/mneedham/algorithms2/blob/master/shortestpath/g_small.txt

It's mostly uninteresting except for the nested loops about half way down. I've tried to vectorise it using numpy but I'm not really sure how to do it given that the matrix/2D array gets changed on each iteration.

If anyone has any ideas on what I need to do or even something to read that would help me on my way that'd be awesome.

==================

I wrote an updated version to take Jaime's comment into account:

```
s=0

def initialise_cache(vertices, s):
    cache = [0 for k in xrange(vertices)]
    cache[s] = 0

    for v in range(0, vertices):
        if v != s:
            cache[v] = float("inf")
    return cache    

cache = initialise_cache(vertices, s)

for i in range(1, vertices):
    previous_cache = deepcopy(cache)
    cache = initialise_cache(vertices, s)
    for v in range(0, vertices):
        adjacent_nodes = adjacency_list[v]

    least_adjacent_cost = float("inf")
    for node in adjacent_nodes:
        adjacent_cost = previous_cache[node["from"]-1] + node["weight"]
        if adjacent_cost < least_adjacent_cost:
            least_adjacent_cost = adjacent_cost

    cache[v] = min(previous_cache[v], least_adjacent_cost)
```

================

And another new version this time using vectorisation:

```
def initialise_cache(vertices, s):
    cache = empty(vertices)
    cache[:] = float("inf")
    cache[s] = 0
    return cache    

adjacency_matrix = zeros((vertices, vertices))
adjacency_matrix[:] = float("inf")
for line in file.readlines():
    tail, head, weight = line.split(" ")
    adjacency_matrix[int(head)-1][int(tail)-1] = int(weight)    

n = vertices
shortest_paths = []
s=2

cache = initialise_cache(vertices, s)
for i in range(1, vertices):
    previous_cache = cache
    combined = (previous_cache.T + adjacency_matrix).min(axis=1)
    cache = minimum(previous_cache, combined)

shortest_paths.append([s, cache])
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read, try following the norm and using 4 space indentation: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know that was the norm, thought t'was 2 spaces like Ruby. Sorted now hopefully!

Comment: I've been fooling around with this for a while, and I have some comments... Your `for i` loop cannot be vectorized, but the `for v` could, although it would require turning `adjacency_list` into one or more arrays. Can you know before hand the maximum adjacent nodes for any node? I'm guessing you could always create a `(vertices, vertices)` array, but that can be an awful lot of storage. Related to this, why do you make your `cache` `vertices` rows long, when you only use the last one? I think you could manage the whole thing in a single list.

Comment: @Jaime I updated the post to make the changes that you suggested - it now only uses a single list instead of the array. I wasn't sure exactly what you meant about the maximum adjacent nodes bit - I'm not sure how you could calculate that before hand given that it makes use of the values from the cache...?

Comment: @MarkNeedham is your problem solved ? If so just answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following vectorised code after following Jaime's advice:

```
def initialise_cache(vertices, s):
    cache = empty(vertices)
    cache[:] = float("inf")
    cache[s] = 0
    return cache    

adjacency_matrix = zeros((vertices, vertices))
adjacency_matrix[:] = float("inf")
for line in file.readlines():
    tail, head, weight = line.split(" ")
    adjacency_matrix[int(head)-1][int(tail)-1] = int(weight)    

n = vertices
shortest_paths = []
s=2

cache = initialise_cache(vertices, s)
for i in range(1, vertices):
    previous_cache = cache
    combined = (previous_cache.T + adjacency_matrix).min(axis=1)
    cache = minimum(previous_cache, combined)

shortest_paths.append([s, cache])
```